# Railo 4 MissingInclude

Tags: windows, tomcat, include, railo

I am running Windows 2008 R2 with Railo 4.

I am having a problem with Railo 4 not seeing the virtual directories defined in IIS.

I know that in ColdFusion 8, I just define the virtual directory in IIS and it works.

However with Railo 4, I am getting the error of "Railo 4.0.4.001 Error (missinginclude)" on a virtual directory already mapped in IIS.

Is there something else I have to define that I don't know about?

Comment: "_I am having a problem with Railo 4 not seeing the virtual directories defined in IIS._"  What do you mean? Railo will know nothing about virtual directories in IIS. Judging from your error message, are you trying to `cfinclude` a template? If so, you probably need to define `mappings`. Can you share the CFML that is generating that error?

Comment: I think you are right about the mappings.  I thought it was like Coldfusion 8 (which I currently run) that reads the virtual directories from IIS accordingly and just works.  I noticed only one set of mappings, is there a way to associate different mappings with different virtual hosts in IIS?

Comment: Mappings are used for things like `cfinclude` and `cfmodule` tags. I thought you said in an earlier comment that your error was not related to these tags.  Virtual directories are used by web servers to access a given directory via the URL in your browser. ColdFusion 8 does not read virtual directories either. It is beginning to sound like you are trying to access a page from your browser but it is not processing the CFM template. You need to provide more details.

Comment: After your first post, I  realized that Tomcat / Railo was completely independent of IIS and it is likely that Tomcat / Railo was not aware of the virtual directories defined in IIS as Coldfusion was (at least the way I was using them). Basically, I am trying to redirect my cart to a secure site and the secure site has virtual directories mapped in IIS to the CFM templates to process the request.  In CF8, it works flawlessly and I am not sure why I am getting "Railo 4.0.4.001 Error (missinginclude)" in Railo.

Comment: You need to look at the connector.  That is what tells IIS to pass requests for the `*.cfm` files to Railo.  Does the parent directory of your virtual directory have the connector defined?  Do `*.cfm` files work in that folder?

Comment: It turns out to be that Railo has a web administrator for every website.  I did not know that as Coldfusion had only one for all websites.  I ended up logging into the web administrator for the secure site, setup the mappings and it works well.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be that Railo has a web administrator for every website. I did not know that as Coldfusion had only one for all websites. I ended up logging into the web administrator for the secure site, setup the mappings and it works well.